# how to set browser compatibility in netbeans jsp application

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, html, jsp

I'm making a jsp web based application some of the buttons and labels are not visible with internet explore but it is good with google chrome.How do i set application compatiblity so that user can see it in very good in handling with all browser

Answer (score 1):

The browser compatibility is not dependent on the Java/JSP code, but on the HTML/CSS/JS code it generates. You, as being a web developer, should usually have full control over this. If you use a [HTML **strict** doctype](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/) and write HTML code according the w3 standards (i.e. the page passes at least the [w3 validator](http://validator.w3.org)) and you use jQuery for writing JavaScript functions, then you have basically nothing to worry about.

Left behind CSS, this may be a pain when you use a wrong HTML doctype which pushes MSIE in the so-called ["quirks mode"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) (which reveals the [MSIE box model bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug)). So you'd like to get at least the doctype straight first (to start, use the HTML5 `<!DOCTYPE html>`). This should solve most of MSIE CSS issues and you can then fix the remaining CSS issues individually. More than often it concerns IE6/7 CSS specific bugs which boils down to the [hasLayout](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html) bug. It's impossible to elaborate all those bugs in detail in a single answer. For that you can better ask a separate and specific question here whenever you stucks with fixing an individual CSS issue.